# Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' when when running setup.py

Tags: python, python-3.x, pip, packaging, pypi

I'm following [Python's Packaging Projects](https://packaging.python.org/tutorials/packaging-projects/) tutorial and when it tells to run `python3 setup.py sdist bdist_wheel` I receive the following error:

```
PS C:\Users\username\dev\packaging_tutorial> python setup.py sdist
 bdist_wheel
  File "setup.py", line 1
SyntaxError: Non-UTF-8 code starting with '\xff' in file setup.py on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/ for details
```

I have no idea why I get this error since my setup.py file is identical to theirs. Has anyone had the same problem?

Comment: Its possible that the text editor you're using is not encoding in utf-8.

Comment: You've probably saved the file as UTF-8 from an editor that puts a BOM at the front.

Comment: P.S. Did you read the PEP that the error pointed you to?

Comment: But then it wouldn't be _non-UTF-8_ because the BOM is always a zero width no-break space in the respective encoding, so in UTF-8 it would be a _UTF-8 encoded_ zero width no-break space. In fact, a UTF-8 BOM would be `EF BB BF` (which doesn't contain `FF`). Sounds more like UTF-16 or UTF-32.

Comment: I'm sorry for the delay in my response, I use VS Code and as far as I know it is using whatever encoding is the default (I believe it is UTF 8).

Answer (score 3):

You are getting this error since the file is created with the default encoding type of powershell, Windows-1252. You'll have to change the encoding type of the file to UTF-8, which python can recognize as python executable. You can achieve this by using the command chcp 65001

Comment: a \xff byte is unlikely to indicate Windows-1252 encoding, because in that encoding it means `ÿ`. It is very likely to indicate UTF-16, when reported (as here) in line 1, because a byte-order mark encoded in UTF-16 will include such a byte (regardless of endianness).